# How to display results of NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, evaluation

I am solving differential equation of second order

```
g = 9.81
k = 0.009
r = 10
b = 0
ω = Sqrt[g/r]

s = NDSolve[{r/g*y''[x] + (k*r/g + b*r^2/mg)*y'[x]^2 + Cos[x] - k*Sin[x] == 0, 
            y[0] == π/2, y'[0] == ω, y, {x, 0, 2}]
```

and I know hot to display the result.

```
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. s], {x, 0, 1.8}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[Evaluate[y'[x] /. s], {x, 0, 1.8}, PlotRange -> All]
```

But I do not know how to display y' as function of y, i.e. y'[y].

I would also like to know how to find the value of x for `y=-\[Pi]/2`.

Is this possible?

Thanks for help

Comment: In your ODE you have the variable `mg` not `m*g`. Interesting `NDSolve` gives nor error message. What do I overlook?

Comment: @Willinski, the fact that b==0?

Comment: @panda-34 ok, I get it.

Comment: @Willinski Yes, it is error.  Fortunately I put b=0 in order to simplify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = NDSolveValue[{r/g*y''[x] + (k*r/g + b*r^2/mg)*y'[x]^2 + Cos[x] - k*Sin[x] == 0, 
                  y[0] == π/2, y'[0] == ω}, y, {x, 0, 2}];
Plot[{s[x], s'[x]}, {x, 0, 1.8}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ParametricPlot[{s[x], s'[x]}, {x, 0, 1.8}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Gosh, this is so easy, just use `NDSolveValue` instead of `NDSolve`.  Is there any reason why should one use the latter instead of former?

Comment: @Pygmalion Yes, `NDSolve` returns replacement rules that are a fundamental Mathematica construct. You just don't need them in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
g = 9.81;
k = 0.009;
r = 10;
b = 0;
ω = Sqrt[g/r];

s = First@NDSolve[{r/g*y''[x] + (k*r/g + b*r^2/mg)*y'[x]^2 + Cos[x] - k*Sin[x] == 0, y[0] == π/2, y'[0] == ω, y, {x, -5, 1}];

ParametricPlot[{y[t] /. s, y'[t] /.s}, {t, 0, 2}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

`y` Doesn't take on the value `-π/2` for positive `x`:

```
Plot[{-(π/2), y[t] /. s}, {t, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

So:

```
FindRoot[Evaluate[-(π/2) == y[t] /. s], {t, -2}]
(* {t -> -1.85664} *)
```