# Why doesn't NDSolve notice the unknown variable inside the equation?

Tags: evaluation, symbolic

```
g = 9.81;
k = 0.009;
r = 10;
b = 0;
ω = Sqrt[g/r];

NDSolve[{r/g*y''[x] + (k*r/g + b*r^2/mg)*y'[x]^2 + Cos[x] - k*Sin[x] == 0, 
        y[0] == π/2, y'[0] == ω}, y, {x, 0, 2}]
```

Regarding to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96928/how-to-display-results-of-ndsolve) question, `NDSolve` evaluates the ODE without an error message. `NDSolve` doesn't evaluate the  term `b*r^2/mg` because `b == 0`, although the variable `mg` is unknown. This is not correct in my opinion.

Is it a bug?

Comment: No, it's not a bug, and it's _not related_ to `NDSolve`.  Take the equation and evaluate it without `NDSolve`.  The `b*...` part will disappear due to `b` being 0.   Essentially you are asking: "Is it correct that `0/mg` automatically evaluates to `0` without `mg` having a value?"

Comment: That question about `0/mg` getting auto-simplified has been brought up before.  [Here's one related thread.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65624/12)  There are others I cannot find right now.

Comment: @Szabolcs Unusually behaviour, `mg` can be `text` or anything and yetl it will be solved! `NDSolve[{r/g*y''[x] + (k*r/g + b*r^2/"abc ")*y'[x]^2 + Cos[x] - 
    k*Sin[x] == 0, y[0] == \[Pi]/2, y'[0] == \[Omega]}, y, {x, 0, 2}]`

Comment: It is not `0/mg`, it is NDSolve, a numeric processor. Before it solves, all variables must be known as numeric.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my comment.  `NDSolve` never sees `0/mg` because `0/mg` immediately evaluates to `0`.  What you see has absolutely nothing to do with `NDSolve`.  When you type `NDSolve[args]`, first `args` are evaluated, `NDSolve` is only processed afterwards.

Comment: Guys, I think the issue behind this question is interesting and (as far as I can tell) not discussed in this site, how about reopening it? (For more details see my answer below. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue behind this question is actually interesting. Not-so-experienced *Mathematica* users often suffer an **illusion**: *the internal functions will merge when they are used together.*

In your case, you probably felt that `NDSolve` together with the equations and initial conditions have merged to *something* that will solve the ODE. "So, what happened inside this *something*?" "Hmm, I don't know, and I believe no body knows, it happened internally." Unfortunately, as said above, it's **generally not true**. When functions are used together, they will just execute from inner to outer. (This order will be adjusted by attributes like `HoldAll`, `HoldFirst`, etc. of course.)

A choice to show the process is to use `Trace`, you can also try the functions in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29339/1871). Here I'll use [WReach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/142/wreach)'s `traceView2`:

```
NDSolve[{r/g y''[x] + (k r/g + b r^2/mg) y'[x]^2 + Cos[x] - k Sin[x] == 0, 
        y[0] == π/2, y'[0] == ω}, y, {x, 0, 2}] // traceView2
```

[image]
*Pictured by Simon Wood's [shadow](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43187/1871).*

As you see, the equation inside `NDSolve` is executed before `NDSolve` begins to work.

Comment: A very clear explanation, thank's @xzczd for your effort. Yes, now I know Mathematica's working method. As a person, who deals daily with formulae, It makes me sick to my stomach when I think I can mix apples and pears, multiply it with zero, and now I'm ready to hand over the solution to a numeric solver. No hard feelings, I shall never forget Mathematica' s working method.