# Weird behaviour for a vector InterpolatingFunction inside an NDSolve

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, interpolation

I have run into some weird behaviour on the part of `NDSolve` which I find pretty bizarre and which I would like to understand better.

Suppose, for the sake of argument, that I want to study the ODE system
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
y'(x)=\cos(x)\phantom{y(x)}\\
z'(x)=y(x),\phantom{\cos(x)}
\end{array}\right.
$$
and that I want to do it sequentially. This is pretty easy: I begin by solving the first equation and setting the resulting `InterpolatingFunction` to a placeholder `f`,

```
f = y /. First[NDSolve[{y'[x] == Cos[x], y[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 20}]]
```

and then I use this `f` inside the second `NDSolve`,

```
NDSolve[{z'[x] == f[x], z[0] == 0}, z, {x, 0, 20}]
```

and everything is dandy.

Going a bit further down For The Sake Of Argument alley, suppose that for whatever reason I want my forcing functions and dependent variables to have vector values (with a single entry). I need to adjust the initial conditions to match, but otherwise everything works fine:

```
g = y /. First[NDSolve[{y'[x] == {Cos[x]}, y[0] == {0}}, y, {x, 0, 20}]]
NDSolve[{z'[x] == g[x], z[0] == {0}}, z, {x, 0, 20}]
```

Now finally, suppose that some devious, argumentative trickster decides to sneak in to change the `g[x]` and add a zero of appropriate dimensions, changing that right-hand side to `{0}+g[x]`, so the command will look like

```
NDSolve[{z'[x] == {0} + g[x], z[0] == {0}}, z, {x, 0, 20}]
```

"That's not a problem!", I hear you say, "surely that's not something that will cause *Mathematica* to just suddenly throw its hands up in the air and give up, right?", and I wholeheartedly agree with you.

Unfortunately, that's not really the case. For some reason, that last bit seems to simply be too much, and *Mathematica* returns the whole `NDSolve` construct undigested:

[image]

Now this is pretty weird. Watering down the `NDSolve` commands to non-evaluating `ndsolve`s throws some light into what's going on: when the arguments to the solver are processed, adding the explicit `{0}` to the symbolic `g[x]` results in the equation `z'[x]=={g[x]}`, where the right-hand side is one level too deep:

[image]

As such, putting in an explicit part statement on the `g`, or making the initial condition for `z` one level deeper will produce mostly acceptable results (or at least, it will produce results, but the second option gives the wrong shape). Thus

```
NDSolve[{z'[x] == {0} + g[x][[1]], z[0] == {0}}, z, {x, 0, 20}]
NDSolve[{z'[x] == {0} + g[x], z[0] == {{0}}}, z, {x, 0, 20}]
```

produces

[image]

Now this is sort of acceptable (at least it sort of kind of fixes the problem) but it feels like a horrible kludge to me.

Mostly, though, I'm deeply uncomfortable with the fact that expressions which look equivalent (`g[x]` and `{0}+g[x]`) produce wildly different results, in an unstable, you-can't-know-what-you'll-get sort of way. Is there a unified way to ensure a more uniform output in this sort of situation?

Comment: I think this is the same as `{a} + b == {a + b}`, where `b` is your `InterpolatingFunction` object. If `List` is not the `Head` of `b`, then `Plus`, being `Listable` will absorb that `b` into `List[a]`. I'm betting there is probably no getting around this.

Comment: @march is right, `{0} + g[x]` will evaluate to `{g[x]}` before `NDSolve` execute. I think you'll find this post interesting: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97006/1871

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@march pointed out](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105594/weird-behaviour-for-a-vector-interpolatingfunction-inside-an-ndsolve#comment286810_105594) the source of the issue:

> I think this is the same as `{a} + b == {a + b}`, where `b` is your `InterpolatingFunction` object. If `List` is not the Head of `b`, then `Plus`, being `Listable` will absorb that `b` into `List[a]`. I'm betting there is probably no getting around this. – march Feb 3 '16 at 22:22

The OP presents a workaround that is a bit unsatisfactory in that the array depth of the result is increased unnecessarily.  I'll present a different workaround that avoids this.  The difficulty can be averted if we can prevent lists/vectors being combined with expressions that do not evaluate to lists until `x` is numeric.  In other words, we have to protect vector-valued expressions from evaluating to lists until `x` is numeric.

```
g = y /. First[NDSolve[{y'[x] == {Cos[x]}, y[0] == {0}}, y, {x, 0, 20}]]
const[x_?NumericQ] := {0};
NDSolve[{z'[x] == const[x] + g[x], z[0] == {0}}, z, {x, 0, 20}]
```

[image]