# Numerically solving a system of ODEs where the functions are vectorized

Tags: differential-equations, matrix

I am attempting to solve a system of ODEs where `a`, `b`, `cv1` and `cv2` are vectors.

```
Tu = {{-3 / 4, 1 / 4}, {5, -6}}`
tu = {2/4, 1}
pu = {.7, .3}

a[y_] = {Subscript[a, 1][y], Subscript[a, 2][y]};
b[y_] = {Subscript[b, 1][y], Subscript[b, 2][y]};
cv1[y_] = {Subscript[cv1, 1][y], Subscript[cv1, 2][y]}
cv2[y_] = {Subscript[Subscript[cv2, 1][y], 1], Subscript[Subscript[cv2, 2][y], 2]}

(* Ode system *)
a'[y] == a[y].Tu
b'[y] == Tu.b[y]
cv1'[y] == Tu.cv1[y] + Subscript[a, 1][y].tu
cv2'[y] == Tu.cv2[y] + Subscript[a, 2][y].tu*)
    
S = 
  NDSolve[
    {a'[y] == a[y].Tu,
     b'[y] == Tu.b[y],
     cv1'[y] == Tu.cv1[y] + Subscript[a, 1][y].tu,
     cv2'[y] == Tu.cv2[y] + Subscript[a, 2][y].tu, a[0] == pu, 
     b[0] == tu, cv1[0] == cv2[0] == 10^-5}, 
   {a[y], b[y], cv1[y], cv2[y] }, {y, 0, ∞}]
```

I am getting an output informing me that there (incorrectly) exist more dependent variables than equations. How should I specify this system?

#### Edit

I fixed the initial code (the above is now the updated version); the previous error no longer occurs, though I now receive the following:

> NDSolve::ndnco: The number of constraints (6) (initial conditions) is not equal to the total differential order of the system plus the number of discrete variables (8).

EDIT:

> Note that using the system as specified in the answer will not retrieve the correct `cv1` and `cv2` expressions. Instead specify those in the system as:

```
cv1'[y] == 
 Tu.cv1[y] + (MapIndexed[Indexed[a[y], #2] &, Range[2]] // First)*tu,
cv2'[y] == 
 Tu.cv2[y] + (MapIndexed[Indexed[a[y], #2] &, Range[2]] // Last)*tu
```

Comment: There is no initial data.

Comment: My bad, I updated it with the correct initial data and am getting new errors as will be listed

Comment: It's just unclear to me what system you're trying to solve. Is `Subscript[a, 1][y]` and `Subscript[a, 2][y]` scalar? If so, why there exists `Subscript[a, 1][y].tu` in the system? (`Dot` (`.`) is for products of vectors, matrices, and tensors. ) Is `cv2` just a vector like `a`, `b` and `cv1`? If so, why is it defined in such a strange way? Can you show us the system in traditional math notation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Tu = {{-3/4, 1/4}, {5, -6}};

tu = {2/4, 1};
pu = {.7, .3};
ym = 1;


(*Ode system*)
eq = {a'[y] == a[y].Tu, b'[y] == Tu.b[y], 
   cv1'[y] == Tu.cv1[y] + First[a[y]]*tu, 
   cv2'[y] == Tu.cv2[y] + Last[a[y]]*tu};
ic = {a[0] == pu, b[0] == tu, cv1[0] == cv2[0] == {10^-5, 10^-5}};



S = NDSolve[{eq, ic}, {a, b, cv1, cv2}, {y, 0, ym}]

{Plot[a[y] /. S, {y, 0, ym}, AxesLabel -> {"y", "a"}], 
 Plot[b[y] /. S, {y, 0, ym}, AxesLabel -> {"y", "b"}, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[cv1[y] /. S, {y, 0, ym}, AxesLabel -> {"y", "cv1"}], 
 Plot[cv2[y] /. S, {y, 0, ym}, AxesLabel -> {"y", "cv2"}]}
```

[image: fig1]

If we change the code, excluding `First` and `Last`, the result will change, although in symbolic form the equations look the same.

```
(*Ode system*)
eq = {a'[y] == a[y].Tu, b'[y] == Tu.b[y], 
   cv1'[y] == Tu.cv1[y] + (a[y].{1, 0})*tu, 
   cv2'[y] == Tu.cv2[y] + (a[y].{0, 1})*tu};
ic = {a[0] == pu, b[0] == tu, cv1[0] == cv2[0] == {10^-5, 10^-5}};
S = NDSolve[{eq, ic}, {a, b, cv1, cv2}, {y, 0, ym}];
{Plot[a[y] /. S, {y, 0, ym}, AxesLabel -> {"y", "a"}], 
 Plot[b[y] /. S, {y, 0, ym}, AxesLabel -> {"y", "b"}, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[cv1[y] /. S, {y, 0, ym}, AxesLabel -> {"y", "cv1"}], 
 Plot[cv2[y] /. S, {y, 0, ym}, AxesLabel -> {"y", "cv2"}]}
```

[image: fig2]

I assume that functions `First` and `Last`
 are ignored when solving equations. @Janeiro offers its solution.

Comment: A colleague who had coded this in R had noted that he had different forms for CV1 and CV2 -- is the First[] and Last[] commands here proper in the system of equations wrt a's elements?

Comment: Problem solved. Use : cv1'[y] == 
 Tu.cv1[y] + (MapIndexed[Indexed[a[y], #2] &, Range[2]] // First)*tu,
cv2'[y] == 
 Tu.cv2[y] + (MapIndexed[Indexed[a[y], #2] &, Range[2]] // Last)*tu (will update question)

Comment: The result is the same. What is the point of adding?

Comment: @Janeiro You are right, really `NDSolve[] ` ignores `First[]` and `Last[]`. I published the second solution.

Comment: `NDSolve` doesn't ignore `First` and `Last`, because they've already disappeared when the `eq=…` line is executed: `First@a[y]` evaluates to `y` immediately. Notice most functions for list manipulation are not limited to `List` manipulation e.g. try `{First@f[x], Most@f[x,y,z]}`.

Comment: @xzczd We can eliminate  `eq` and put the equations right in `NDSolve[]`. Then we will see that `NDSolve` ignores that `First[]` and `Last[]` acts on the list `a[y]` and takes `a[y]` as a scalar. Although in calculations `a[y]` is taken as a vector. This is ridiculous.

Comment: Eliminating `eq` doesn't change anything, because `NDSolve` doesn't have attribute `HoldAll` or `HoldFirst` etc. so the first argument of `NDSolve` i.e. the equation system will be evaluated before sending into `NDSolve`. Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97006/1871

Comment: @xzczd Thanks, I understand, but it is funny that the function in the same row is considered both as a vector and as a scalar.