# Using Flatten inside NDSolve

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, tensors

I'm using `Flatten` to contract a rank 4 tensor and a matrix (rank 2 tensor) inside `NDSolve` and there seems to be error. Here is my code

```
g = 1;
tbar = 30;
n = 4;
d0 = IdentityMatrix[n];
d = Table[If[i == j - 1, Sqrt[j], 0], {i, 0, n - 1}, {j, 0, n - 1}];
h = N[Outer[Times, Transpose[d].d, d0] + 
    Outer[Times, d0, Transpose[d].d] + g*
     Outer[Times, d + Transpose[d], 
      d + Transpose[d]]];
c0 = Table[If[i == 1 && j == 1, 1, 0], {i, 0, n - 1}, {j, 0, n - 1}];
sol = NDSolve[{c'[t] == -I*
      Flatten[h, {{1}, {3}, {2, 4}}].Flatten[c[t], {1, 2}], 
    c[0] == c0}, c, {t, 0, tbar}];
```

I get the error

> [image]

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Flatten[c[t], {1, 2}]` is wrong There is nothing to Flatten here. That is what the error is saying basically. Why do you want to Flatten `c[t]` for?

Comment: @Nasser I want to contract the 2nd and 4th indices of the tensor h with the 2 indices of the matrix c. This is a valid operation. I say this because if you did this with h and c0 the output is another matrix. So I'm not sure what you mean when you say this is wrong. can you please explain why?

Comment: **can you please explain why?**  Well, what do you expect the result of `Flatten[c[t], {1, 2}]` to be?  `c[t]` is not a list.  If you just type `Flatten[c[t], {1, 2}]` on its own, you will see the error.

Comment: @Nasser Evaluation order isn't that easy for beginners…

Comment: @Nasser my confusion was with evaluation order as is clear now with the other answers.

Comment: Related, although it's primarily about allowing evaluation only when the argument is numeric (as opposed to a tensor), but the basic idea is similar: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another question evaluation order. `NDSolve` is a function doesn't own attributes like `HoldAll`, `HoldFirst`, etc, the equation will evaluate before it's passed into `NDSolve`: at this point the `c[t]` isn't a tensor yet! So the warning `Flatten::fldep` pops up. (For a more detailed explanation, you may want to read [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97006/1871). )

One possible solution is, as shown [by cvgmt](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/272617/1871), avoid `Flatten` of `c[t]`, another possible solution is, define a black-box helper function that evaluates only when its argument is a `List`:

```
rhsfunc[c_List] := -I*Flatten[h, {{1}, {3}, {2, 4}}] . Flatten[c, {1, 2}]

sol = NDSolveValue[{c'[t] == rhsfunc[c[t]], c[0] == c0}, c, {t, 0, tbar}]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! this is exactly what I was confused about

Comment: @pixis Glad it helps. Actually you don't need to accept that fast, it's OK to wait for a while (a day or even longer) to see if better answer(s) come up :) .

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to `Flatten[h, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}]` instead of `Flatten[h, {{1}, {3}, {2, 4}}]`, and `Flatten[c0, {1, 2}]` instead of `Flatten[c[t], {1, 2}]`.

```
g = 1;
tbar = 30;
n = 4;
d0 = IdentityMatrix[n];
d = Table[If[i == j - 1, Sqrt[j], 0], {i, 0, n - 1}, {j, 0, n - 1}];
h = N[Outer[Times, Transpose[d] . d, d0] + 
    Outer[Times, d0, Transpose[d] . d] + 
    g*Outer[Times, d + Transpose[d], d + Transpose[d]]];
c0 = Table[If[i == 1 && j == 1, 1, 0], {i, 0, n - 1}, {j, 0, n - 1}];
sol = NDSolve[{c'[t] == -I*Flatten[h, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}] . c[t], 
   c[0] == Flatten[c0, {1, 2}]}, c, {t, 0, tbar}]
c[2] /. sol[[1]]
```

[image]

Comment: this is a useful way of doing it, I'm accepting the other answer only because it explains better what i was doing wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to flatten `c[t]` while it's a symbol before its value as a tensor during integration is substituted. If you want to have matrix output value, a standard solution is to write your own flatten function that won't evaluate until it is passed an array.

```
g = 1;
tbar = 30;
n = 4;
d0 = IdentityMatrix[n];
d = Table[If[i == j - 1, Sqrt[j], 0], {i, 0, n - 1}, {j, 0, n - 1}];
h = N[Outer[Times, Transpose[d] . d, d0] + 
    Outer[Times, d0, Transpose[d] . d] + 
    g*Outer[Times, d + Transpose[d], d + Transpose[d]]];
c0 = Table[If[i == 1 && j == 1, 1, 0], {i, 0, n - 1}, {j, 0, n - 1}];

myFlatten[t_?ArrayQ, spec_] := Flatten[t, spec];

sol = NDSolve[{c'[t] == -I*
      myFlatten[h, {{1}, {3}, {2, 4}}] . myFlatten[c[t], {1, 2}], 
    c[0] == c0}, c, {t, 0, tbar}];
```

Comment: One could also use a generic conditional evaluation function like `SetAttributes[when, HoldAll];
when[expr_, test_] /; test := expr` and use it thus: `when[Flatten[c[t], {1, 2}], ArrayQ[c[t]]]` to replace `Flatten[c[t], {1, 2}]` in the OP.

Comment: Thanks! this works for, I'm accepting the other answer only because it came first and does the same thing