# PDE involving derivative at boundary, with a boundary condition at infinity

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I am trying to find the function $T(z,t)$ which solves this differential equation:
$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial z^2}+St\left[ \exp\left [ -\frac{\left( x_f-Ut\right )^2}{2\sigma^2} \right ] +\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}(0,t)\right]\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}$$
with the initial condition
$$T(z,0)=T_0(z)$$
where
$$T_0=T_c \exp (-a_1 z_c z)$$
and boundary conditions:
$$T(0,t)=1$$
and
$$T(\infty,t)=0$$
In the differential equation
$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}(0,t)$$
is the derivative of the unknown function $T(z,t)$ calculated at $z=0$, while $x_f$ is calculated as the solution of the folowing equation:
$$\exp\left ( -\frac{ x_f^2}{2\sigma^2} \right ) =-\frac{d T_0}{d z}(z=0)$$
The values of the constants are: $a_1=50$, $St=2$, $U=0.8$, $\sigma=0.4$, $Tc=1500$ and $z_c=0.001$.
I tried the following code, even if I do not know if I have inserted correctly the term $\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}(0,t)$:

```
Tc = 1500
zc = 0.001
tc = 0.1
St = 2
U = 0.8
\[Sigma] = 0.4
a1=50;
T0[z_] := Exp[(-a1)*zc*z]
xf = NSolve[
   Exp[-(x^2/(2*\[Sigma]^2))] == -(D[T0[z], z] /. z -> 0) && x > 0, 
   x][[1, 1, 2]]
solu = NDSolve[{D[T[z, t], {t}] == 
    St*D[T[z, t], {z}]*(D[T[0, t], {z}] + 
        E^(-((xf - t*U)^2/(2*\[Sigma]^2)))) + 
           D[T[z, t], {z, 2}], T[0, t] == 1, T[190, t] == 0, 
   T[z, 0] == T0[z]}, T, {z, 0, 190}, {t, 0, 1000}]
```

I use $190$ to approximate $\infty$ here.
Unfortunately I get an error of the type:

```
General::munfl: exp(-1.99511*10^6) is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.
```

However the result seems to work and

```
D[T0[z], z] /. z -> 0
```

and

```
D[Evaluate[T[z, t] /. First[solu]], z] /. {z -> 0, t -> 0}
```

are quite similar, as they should.
Indeed

```
(D[T0[z], z] /. 
   z -> 0) - (D[Evaluate[T[z, t] /. First[solu]], z] /. {z -> 0, 
    t -> 0})
```

is equal to $-0.0000357858$.
But if I change $190$ to $700$ the previous difference becomes $-0.0036338$. This means that the result is very sensitive to the value used to approximate $\infty$. Is there any way to insert the condition at $\infty$ in `NDSolve` without using a numerical approximation, also because I am interested in studying how $T(z,t)$ varies with $a_1$, and I noticed that varying $a_1$ I need to vary the numerical approximation of $\infty$ to have good results. Many thanks. (Could you please check if I wrote the Mathematica code for the differential equation correctly).

Comment: `D[T[0, t], {z}]` is obviouly wrong. (Just execute it separately and observe! ) `NDSolve` cannot handle this problem directly, you need to discretize yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps `NestList`, assuming `D[T[0, t], {z}]` is known from pervious iteration, helps to find a solution.

```
sol = NestList[
NDSolveValue[{D[T[z, t], {t}] ==St*D[T[z, t], {z}]*(
Derivative[1, 0][#] [0, t] + 
E^(-((xf - t*U)^2/(2*\[Sigma]^2)))) + D[T[z, t], {z, 2}], 
T[0, t] == 1, T[190, t] == 0, T[z, 0] == T0[z]}, 
T, {z, 0, 190}, {t, 0, 1000}] &, 0 &, 10]
```

This gives a solution which seems to converge:

```
Row[{Plot3D[{ sol[[-1]][z, t]} , {z, 0, 190}, {t, 0, 1000},ImageSize -> 200],
Plot3D[{sol[[-2]][z, t] - sol[[-1]][z, t]} , {z, 0, 190}, {t, 0,1000}, ImageSize-> 200]}]
```

[image]

Part `D[T[0, t], {z}]` converges too:

```
Plot[Map[Derivative[1, 0][Function[{z, t}, #[z, t]]][0, t] &,sol[[-5 ;;]]], {t, 0, 1000}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

By the way: You might omit the infinity bc  `T[190, t] == 0` and get  the same result!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you agian. I was surprised by discovering that NDSolve works also without the bc at infinity, since the problem should be ill-posed in this way. Indeed, the kernel issues a warning in this case: an insufficient number of boundary conditions have been specified for the direction of independent variable z.
However, the solution produced without the abovementioned bc is practically identical to the one you get with the bc. Do Mathematica automatically add a bc to close the problem? Is this the meaning of the following warning: artificial boundary effects may be present in the solution.

Comment: @umby No, `NDSolve` doesn't add any b.c., it simply uses one-sided difference formula to close the system. Please notice the `bcart` warning is severe and you should avoid it. For more info, read: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73961/1871

Answer (score 2):

Let me extend my comment to an answer.

First of all, `D[T[0, t], {z}]` is obviouly wrong. Since there's literally no `z` in `T[0, t]`, `D[T[0, t], {z}]` will evaluate to `0`:

[image]

"But `NDSolve` is so powerful! There may be some magic in `NDSolve` so `D[T[0, t], {z}]` will be parsed as I expect!" <- If this is what you're thinking, please notice `NDSolve` doesn't have `HoldAll`/`HoldFirst`/… attribute so its arguments are all evaluated before passed into `NDSolve` i.e. `NDSolve` doesn't even have a chance to analyze the `D[T[0, t], {z}]` term. (A more detailed analysis can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97006/1871). )

"OK, then how to circumvent?" Currently `NDSolve` cannot handle this problem directly. Picard iteration as shown in Ulrich's answer is a way to go. Discretizing the PDE in $z$ direction with [`pdetoode`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) is another:

```
domain = {lb, rb} = {0, 190};
tend = 1000;
With[{T = T[z, t]}, 
    {eq, ic, bc} = 
     {D[T, t] == St D[T, z] (term + E^(-((xf - t U)^2/(2 σ^2)))) + D[T, {z, 2}], 
      T == T0[z] /. t -> 0, 
      {T == 1 /. z -> lb, T == 0 /. z -> rb}};
  termvalue = D[T, z] /. z -> lb];

points = 25; difforder = 4; grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
(* Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoofunc = pdetoode[T[z, t], t, grid, difforder];
del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;

ode = del@ptoofunc@eq /. term -> ptoofunc@termvalue;
odeic = ptoofunc@ic // del;
odebc = ptoofunc@bc;

sollst = NDSolveValue[{ode, odeic, odebc}, T /@ grid, {t, 0, tend}]; // AbsoluteTiming
sol = rebuild[sollst, grid, 2];

Plot3D[sol[z, t], {z, lb, rb}, {t, 0, tend}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[termvalue /. T -> sol // Evaluate, {t, 0, tend}]
```

[image]

Comment: To the downvoter, I am interested in what's wrong with my answer, would you please elaborate. I'm not trying to complain here, I just want improve my answer if possible.

Comment: Dear xzczd, dear Ulrich Neumann, many thanks! your answers really solved my problem, I'm using them both and having fun in solving my pde also changing the initial condition. For this reason I accept them both as a good solution for my problem.

Comment: Dear @xzczd , just to be sure, what is difforder? why difforder is 4 in this case?

Comment: @user58367 It essentially sets the value of `DifferenceOrder` option of ``NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative``, on which `pdetoode` is built. `DifferenceOrder -> 4` is a common choice, another common choice is `2`. Some discussion for this option can be found in the built-in tutorial _The Numerical Method of Lines_.